# How do I properly implement the map function with fetch API in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to insert the data fetched into a map function that returns each employe's name in

, but im getting an error that says "data.map is not a function". How can I fix this>

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

//const data = [{id:1,employee_name:"Tiger Nixon",employee_salary:320800,employee_age:61,profile_image:""},{id:2,employee_name:"Garrett Winters",employee_salary:170750,employee_age:63,profile_image:""}]

export default function App() {
 const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => setData(result))
  },[]);
  const information = data.map((item,i) => {
    return (<h1> item.employee_name </h1>);

  })
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1> {information} </h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Have you tried printing `data` to see what it actually _is_ when the error prints?

Comment: console.log(data) returns this: 
[]
{status: "success", data: Array(24), message: "Successfully! All records has been fetched."}
status: "success"
data: Array(24)
message: "Successfully! All records has been fetched."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the link https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees (where u fetching data)

Notice that it returns an Object NOT an array. the object contains `status` (a string), `data` (array) and `message` (string). The `data` is the part u wish to save. Right now you are saving the entire object hence `.map` is not a function.

There are 2 ways to fix it.

1st save ONLY the `data` into ur state

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => setData(result.data || []))
  },[]);
```

NOTE adding `[]` ensures that if `data` is a null - the array would exist hence `.map` would not throw an error.

OR switching ur state model to an object `const [data, setData] = useState(null);` and rendering like so

```
  const information = data?.data?.map((item,i) => {
    return (<h1> item.employee_name </h1>);
  })
```

NOTE using `?.` is just an IF that `if` it dosent exist. If `data?` has value of `.data`. and `?.map` if the `.data` has a method `.map`. If any of these return false - entire thing returns a null.

Would recommend sticking with the 1st way. But up to you